# C# GCM NotRegistered

Tags: c#, google-cloud-messaging

I'm receiving GCM response NotRegistered and I know it can be an expired registration_id. But, GCM response is not giving me "registration_id" or "canonical_ids" to replace the outdated registration.

Response:

```
{
    "multicast_id": -1,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "NotRegistered"
        }
    ]
}
```

Anyone knows what I have to do to get new registration_id?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Are you really still using GCM? Or is this supposed to be tagged for FCM?

Comment: Hi. Yes, we use GCM and FCM in company that I work. GCM is legacy system and we will change to FCM. But, for now I would like to fix this expired tokens problem and later implement FCM.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [GCM/FCM documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/errors), `NotRegistered` means that the provided registration token is no longer registered. A previously valid registration token can be unregistered for a variety of reasons, including:

- The client app unregistered itself from FCM.
- The client app was automatically unregistered. This can happen if the user uninstalls the application or, on iOS, if the APNS Feedback Service reported the APNS token as invalid.
- The registration token expired. For example, Google might decide to refresh registration tokens or the APNS token may have expired for iOS devices.
- The client app was updated, but the new version is not configured to receive messages.

For all these cases, remove this registration token and stop using it to send messages.

Calling `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()` on that device should return a new valid token.